# comprar dois dataframes com pandas - python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Estou tentando realizar a comparação entre 2 campos, onde 1 é um dataframe e o outro esta em branco, onde após a verificação que os objetos são diferetes(pois futuramente a ideia é salvar um novo dataframe no file2) ele deve imprmir, arquivos diferetens.
Segue abaixo teste do código realizado:

```
from ast import If

import pandas as pd

import testeDiversos as td #importando classe do dataframe

file1 = td.df_infractions


file2 = ""

if (file1 != file2):
    print("Arquivos diferentes")
```

o erro retornado do código a cima é:
ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comparacao de dataframes nao é uma tarefa fácil, mas vou tentar explicar um pouco antes de entrarmos em detalhe no seu código:

A biblioteca Pandas e o methodo DataFrame colocam todos os valores em uma tabela contendo: index, columns e values

Sendo assim `df1!=df2` só serao comparados se:

1- as Colunas estiverem nomeadas identicamente iguais **e** a quantidade de linhas seja identica, caso contrário receberá o erro:

```
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled DataFrame objects
```

2- Se a comparacao ocorrer, voce receberá um df com comparacao individual de cada valor (ou cada célula) entre os dfs,  o que para o seu caso já nao é , na minha opiniao, muito adequado. (False - valores identicos na célula, True valores diferentes, conforme a comparacao `df1 != df2`

```
Ticket  Slope   Var_1
False   True    True
False   True    True
```

3- a sua comparacao com um df (vazio) retornará um df completo de Trues, já que todos os valores sao diferentes.

3.1- O comando if, funciona apenas para valores e, conforme disse, voce está comparando tabelas, por isso a funcao retorna um erro.

Bom acho que é hora da sua resposta, para isso criei aqui alguns dfs básicos para ajudar a resposta e para voce tentar aí também:

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

length = 5 # tamanho do df (linhas)
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Service': np.arange(length),
               'Ticket': np.random.rand(length),
               'Slope' : np.random.randint(-50,2,size=length),
               'Var_1': np.random.rand(length)})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Service': np.arange(length),
               'Ticket': np.random.randint(length),
               'Slope' : np.random.randint(-50,2,size=length),
               'Var_1': np.random.rand(length)})
df3 ='' # df vazio

df4 = df1[:] # df clonado (exatamente igual)

df5 = pd.DataFrame({'Service': np.arange(length), 
                   'Ticket': np.random.rand(length)})# qtde de colunas diferentes
```

Vamos agora usar as minhas observacoes:

```
df1!=df5 # 1 ERRO
df1!=df2 # 2 retorna um df com True onde diferente e False se os valores forem iguais.
df1!=df3 # 3 todos os valores `True`, já que df3 está vazio
df1!=df4 # 4 todos os valores `False`, df foi clonado
```

Mas entao, como fazer? Para isso voce terá que fazer um `merge`, entre os dois dataframes ( válido apenas para o caso do `df2` **nao estar vazio** e ter ao menos o nome de uma coluna em comum, no meu exemplo 'Ticket')

```
df_12 = df1.merge(df2.drop_duplicates(), on=['Ticket'], 
               how='left', indicator=True)
```

Este novo df_12 está mesclando (nao é juntando) através de colunas, retirando as duplicadas na coluna selecionada 'Ticket', e retornando um idicador, caso hajam valores semelhantes em ambas (both) ou nao (apenas do df do lado esquerdo, df1).

Se houverem colunas semelhantes, ele adicionara um sufixo com os valores _X (df1, esquerdo) e _Y(df2,direito)

```
Ticket  Slope_x Var_1_x Service_y   Slope_y Var_1_y _merge
0   8   -25 0.056275    4.0 -13.0   0.214676    both
1   3   -33 0.911474    1.0 0.0 0.202241    both
2   8   -5  0.927864    4.0 -13.0   0.214676    both
3   4   -10 0.551897    NaN NaN NaN left_only
4   1   -15 0.888120    NaN NaN NaN left_only
```

Lembre-se que o exemplo acima usa expressoes randomicas e os resultados podem variar dos meus resultados aqui.

Espero ter eclarecido um pouco e sugiro um pouco mais de pesquisa, para ter certeza que a biblioteca pandas é a mais adequada para a sua atividade.

Sucesso